# How to run Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management Service using a domain account

Tags: hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I have an Domain account with admin priviliges and I need to use that account to run the Hyper-v Machine Management Service.  my goal is to use that domain account to create VMs using ISO files that are in a different server within the same domain.  I was told that if I use the local account to do this things may not work.

How do I run the Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management Service under a domain account?

Comment: To clarify, you want to simply start-up a new VM and boot to an ISO file on a different server?

Comment: Ah, the mysterious "I was told that if I use the local account to do this things may not work". - 1. Who told you? 2. What "things"? 3. What might not work with these "things"?

Comment: what version of hyper-v, prior to 2012 this was not supported but you can make it work. don't start the service with a domain admin account, just use the local system account then put server$ on the remote share that you iso sits on.  if needed I can find a doc that shows how this is done.

Answer (score 2):

this link http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2008/06/24/storing-windows-server-2008-hyper-v-files-on-an-cifs-smb-file-share.aspx

Storing your Hyper-V files on a file server is pretty straightforward.
There are, however, a few of things that you need to implement this properly with Hyper-V.

First of all, remember to grant access to the computer account of the computer running Hyper-V. 
This is the DOMAIN\COMPUTERNAME$ account, which you can use in the same way you would use a regular user account when granting permissions.

The second thing is that you need to do is use a UNC path when pointing to the file server. 
This is a path that looks like \SERVERNAME\SHARENAME. 
Using a mapped drive or mount point does not work with the Hyper-V Manager tool.

Last but not least, you need to do this at the computer running Hyper-V (or connected via Remote Desktop to that computer).
If you try to use the Hyper-V Manager tool remotely, you will get an error message saying "Failed to create external configuration store at '\SERVERNAME\SHARENAME\FOLDERNAME': General access denied error (0x80070005)".
You can work around this by using constrained delegation to allow a workstation to work on behalf of the computer running Hyper-V.
For details on that option, check http://blogs.technet.com/josebda/archive/2008/06/27/using-constrained-delegation-to-remotely-manage-a-server-running-hyper-v-that-uses-cifs-smb-file-shares.aspx.